# What is an alternative to the broken WoW API call GetCurrentRegion()?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to fix a problem in the "Ask Mr. Robot" add-on for World of Warcraft.

The buggy code goes something like this:

```
function AskMrRobot.ScanCharacter()
    AmrDb.Region = AskMrRobot.regionNames[GetCurrentRegion()]

    -- other stuff here
end
```

The problem is that `GetCurrentRegion()` returns the client region and not the logged in region: I have a EU client logged in on a US realm which has a EU counterpart with the same name (Area52). The net effect is that the plugin returns an existing, but incorrect realm ("EU-Area52"), instead of the existing and correct one ("US-Area52").

This problem is also documented on [gamepedia](http://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetCurrentRegion)

> This function is unreliable for players who switch between regions. For example, if a player installs the US client and then logs into EU servers, this function will incorrectly report that they are still in the US region.

So, I'd like to replace the `GetCurrentRegion()` with an alternative call or function which returns reliable data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the library **LibRealmInfo** ([WoWI](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info22987-LibRealmInfo.html)/[Curse](http://wow.curseforge.com/addons/librealminfo/)) that provides lookups of hardcoded, hand-collected data to determine the current region in a reliable way *(may fail for new realms added at a later point, so check for updates)*

Other methods that are unreliable:

- The CVar `"portal"` is in fact the value that `GetCurrentRegion()` returns, so it's the same, possibly incorrect value
- As a **[reply](http://www.wowinterface.com/forums/showthread.php?t=48877#15)** in the thread linked by Hotted24 by the infamous Simca states, the CVar `"realmList"` no longer works in WoD. *(may still 'work' - as in not throwing an error when given to `GetCVar` - if it's in Config.wtf, but will most likely not be changed anymore by the Launcher)*

**edit:** sanitized post

Comment: Thanks, I've used the library to fix: https://gist.github.com/sklivvz/b2dc51c4547818e88672

Answer (score -1):

```
local realmlist = GetCVar("realmList")
local region = string.match(realmlist,"(%a+)%..+")
if region then
  -- use region
end
```

Saw it on wowinterface, been using it, working last time I checked =)

[Reference](http://www.wowinterface.com/forums/showthread.php?t=48877)

**EDIT :**

Not tested, but fairly sure it'll work :

```
local guid = UnitGUID("player")
local currentRegion
if guid then
    local server = tonumber(strmatch(guid, "^Player%-(%d+)"))
    local realm = realmData[server]
    if realm then
        currentRegion = realm.region
    end
end
```

[Reference](https://github.com/Phanx/LibRealmInfo/blob/master/LibRealmInfo.lua#L31)

Comment: Your code doesn't work as is, one needs to include the library and call the public methods